# Alternative declarations of a variable depending on an if condition

Tags: c, if-statement, variable-declaration

I would like to have as, if i is 1 then a as int type otherwise as char type,but when i compile this code then it encounters below error:

```
> 1.c: In function ‘main’:
> 1.c:18:16: error: ‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>              if(a)
>                 ^
> 1.c:18:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in



  #include <stdio.h>
    #define macro
    void main()
    {
        int i=1;
    #ifdef macro
        if (i==1)
        {
            int a;
        }
        else
    #endif
        {
            char a;
        }
        if(a)
        {
        printf("INDOE ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Variables have a scope of a block they are declared in.

Comment: You could declare `a` as an `int` then conditionally cast it to a `char` when necessary?

Comment: What do you want to actually do with a?

Comment: If this was C++, you would use a template (provided the value of `i` is known at compile time).

Comment: rohit  Are you familiar with `union`?

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Why do you have half of the if in the macro? What do you want this code to do?

Answer (score 3):

> i would like to have as, if i is 1 then a as int type otherwise as char type

Stop right here, compiled C code doesn't know about types, so you can't set a type at runtime -- it's already "hardcoded" the time you compile your program.

Side note:

```
    {
        char a;
    }
    if(a)
```

The braces give the variable a **scope**, so after the closing brace, `a` doesn't exist any more.

---

There are many ways to solve this, they all involve that you store your own type information. Rough idea:

```
enum mytype { MT_INT, MT_CHAR };

struct myvalue {
    enum mytype type;
    union {
        int a_int;
        char a_char;
    };
};


[...]

struct myvalue x;
// [...]
if (i==1) x.type = MT_INT;
else x.type = MT_CHAR;
// [...]
```

Then in each access of `x.a_int` or `x.a_char`, check `x.type` first to know which member to access.

Comment: "can't set a type at runtime" --> VLA allow for limited run-time type variation -the array size.

Comment: @chux while this is obviously correct, I can't think of a way to integrate it in my answer (without distracting too much from the actual point) -- any suggestions?

Comment: It is just  a note to your fine answer.

Answer (score 0):

Scope of a variable in C is limited to the block you have declared it. The int a is available only within the if. And the char a is available only within the else

Answer (score 0):

Search about "scope" concept. A variable, in C, defined in a scope will not be accessible outside it or in a scope above, but is accessible on a scope below.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want your condtional to be handled by the preprocessor. eg.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

#define i 1

#if i
#define ATYPE int
#else
#define ATYPE char
#endif
int main(int argc, char* args)
    {
        ATYPE a;
        printf("%d\n", sizeof(a));
    }
```

I certainly wouldn't recommend #define'ing i, but this looks a bit like what you're trying to do.